# python else if undefined error, view other object

Tags: python, if-statement

If I use command `python main.py -h`, it returns "Home".
If I use command `python main.py -c`, it also returns "Home" and not "a".

Where is the problem?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-   

import sys
import getopt

######################################################################################    
def usage():
    print "Home"
#if __name__ == "__main__":
try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "h:c:u", ["help", "connect", "upload="])
except getopt.GetoptError:
    usage()
    sys.exit(2)

for opt, arg in opts:
    if opt in ("-h", "--help"):
        usage()
    elif opt in ("-u", "--upload"):
        file = args
        if not file:
            print "Nie wybrano pliku!"
        else:
            print "Wybrany plik",file
    elif opt in ("-c", "--connect"):
        print "a"
```

Comment: As an aside, the Python docs say: "The `getopt` module is a parser for command line options whose API is designed to be familiar to users of the C `getopt()` function. Users who are unfamiliar with the C `getopt()` function or who would like to write less code and get better help and error messages should consider using the `argparse` module instead."

Comment: Also, can you think of a better title? Right now, it doesn't appear to have anything to do with the question...

Answer (score 2):

You probably receive getopt.GetoptError exception in both cases, because you listed '-h' and '-c' options as if they require arguments and based on your description you do not pass any.

Consider changing line:

```
opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "h:c:u", ["help", "connect", "upload="])
```

to:

```
opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "hcu:", ["help", "connect", "upload="])
```